# Solving matrix equation $C=A B A^\mathrm{T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

I am writing a code on Matlab to calculate the matrix $B$, given $C$ and $A$, following the equation

$$C=A B A^\mathrm{T}$$

$A^\mathrm{T}$ is non-invertible, so I can't just multiply $C$ by the inverse of the matrices.

I can't solve this by hand either because $C$ is a $3144×3144$ matrix...any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $A$ is not invertible, in general, there may be infinite $B$ which yield the same $C$. Give us more context, please.

Comment: Do you know the dimension of A? The rank of A?

Comment: A is a 740*3144 matrix of the form
A= 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0...;
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0...;
      0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1...;
      ...
The constraint is that C is a symmetric matrix, and B has to be a symmetric matrix too.

Answer (score 1):

For $A(N\times K)$ and $rank(A)=K \leq N$ we have $$B = (A^TA)^{-1}A^TCA(A^TA)^{-1}. $$